# Writing javascript code in Django templates I got an error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, django

This following error is occurring in my console:

**" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"**

```
function updateCart(cart) {
    for (var item in cart) {
        document.getElementById("div" + item).innerHTML = "<button id='minus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary minus'>-</button> <span id='val" + item + "''>" + cart[item] + "</span> <button id='plus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary plus'> + </button>";
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;
    console.log(cart);
}
```

Can someone help me to figure this out please?

Comment: I do not really think this has anything to do with Django, rather than accessing an element which does not exist. Have you tried debugging the cart items to check if there really is a div for each item with that id?

Comment: Check if elements you are trying to access exists ('#div'+item and '#cart')

Comment: {% for i in product %}
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card align-items-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">

Comment: <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{i.desc|slice:"0:53"}}...</p>
                                <span id="divpr{{i.id}}" class="divpr">
                                    <button id="pr{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                                </span>
                                <a href="/shop/products/{{i.id}}"><button id="qv{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">QuickView</button></a>

Answer (score 0):

Your document probably does not contain any element having an id="cart".
Either insert a <div id="cart"></div> into your html code, or protect your script against error as:

```
try {document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;} catch (e){};
```

or:

```
var someplace=document.getElementById('cart');
if (someplace!=null){someplace.innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;};
```

Comment: Actually I am putting js/jquery script links after the function that's why the error was occurring.